# Kivy-ios new toolchain submit ipa file issue

Tags: ios, submit, bundle, kivy, ipa

While submitting ipa file to I'm getting error:

ERROR ITMS-90171: "Invalid Bundle Structure - The binary file 'eplaneo.app/YourApp/myapp-ios/build/myapp.build/Debug-iphoneos/myapp.build/Objects-normal/armv7/myapp' is not permitted. Your app can’t contain standalone executables or libraries, other than the CFBundleExecutable of supported bundles.
Refer to the Bundle Programming Guide at https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFBundles/BundleTypes/BundleTypes.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000123i-CH101-SW1 for information on the iOS app bundle structure."

ERROR ITMS-90171: "Invalid Bundle Structure - The binary file 'eplaneo.app/YourApp/myapp-ios/build/myapp.build/Debug-iphoneos/myapp.build/Objects-normal/arm64/myapp' is not permitted. Your app can’t contain standalone executables or libraries, other than the CFBundleExecutable of supported bundles.
Refer to the Bundle Programming Guide at https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFBundles/BundleTypes/BundleTypes.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000123i-CH101-SW1 for information on the iOS app bundle structure."

ERROR ITMS-90126: "The binary is invalid. The LC_ENCRYPTION_INFO load command is not expected for the bundle executable of eplaneo.app/YourApp/myapp-ios/build/Debug-iphoneos/myapp.app. This binary does not seem to have been built with Apple's linker."

Build with new kivy-ios toolchain (64bit support). Archive created with xcode 6.2. 
Trying to submit with Application Loader 3.0

Anyone had same problem?

Comment: check the following http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28621297/iphone-app-submitting-error-itms-90171-invalid-bundle-structure-cant-contain

Comment: It looks like different case, @casillas

Comment: I had this and fixed it by removing all files ending in '.so.o'. Please try that and post here if it fixes it?