# Unable to upload iOS update after adding Flurry Analytics? Error: Your app can’t contain standalone executables or libraries

Tags: ios, xcode, flurry, flurry-analytics

In my Swift iOS application I've just added Flurry Analytics by creating a `briding-header.h` and `importing Flurry.h`. I then added `SystemConfiguration.framework`, `CFNetwork.framework`, and `Security.framework`.

I then added `libFlurry_6.5.0.a` via `Targets -> Build Phases -> Link Binary with Libraries` after instruction from a Stack Overflow question because it wouldn't build.

After archiving the app I tried to upload it and received this error:

> ERROR ITMS-90171: “Invalid Bundle Structure - The binary file
>   ‘APPNAME.app/Flurry/libFlurry_6.5.0.a’ is not permitted. Your app
>   can’t contain standalone executables or libraries...

Answer (score 19, accepted):

1. Open the **Build Phases** tab in the target settings for your project.
2. Make sure that `Flurry.framework` is not included under **Copy Bundle Resources**.

From [Invalid Bundle Structure](http://onebigfunction.com/ios/2015/03/15/invalid-bundle-structure/).

Comment: Faced same issue. Added OCMock libs for unit test in test target but it was there in Copy Bundle Resource for all other targets. Can you please explain? @Daniel Storm

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem of a different cause:

My project did depend on multiple c++ libraries, which I added to my Xcode project, but only as reference. Then I linked the .a files in Link Binary With Libraries build phase, which works for building and running the project, but throws this error when uploading to the App Store.

I fixed it with deleting the references in my project, and copying the files to my project instead (When adding files to the project, check the mark on "Copy items if needed"). After that I was able to upload my app.

Answer (score -1):

My case was a bit different. I added an static library to "Embed Frameworks" and I got a couple of errors when I uploaded the app to the app store:

1. The binary X is not permitted. Your app can't contain standalone executables or libraries, other than a valid CFBundleExecutable of supported bundles
2. Invalid Swift Support - Doesn't have the correct file type for this location

I removed this dependency and the problem was solved

Comment: If your app needs the dependency, then how is this a valid solution?

Comment: yeah this answer doesn't make sense